# Making a new window with an input widget using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I can't seem to make my new window display the inputer code

it only displays a new empty window without the labels and the input widget

i want to make a simple GUI for a school project, but i dont want to type the name in the python shell, but in the interface

please help and tell me where im wrong, im still new to python

```
from collections import deque
first = deque([])
last = deque([])
nom = 0
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class Application(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, master=None, nom=0, priono=1, prio=1):
    super().__init__(master)

    self.pack()
    self.create_widgets()
    self.nom= nom
    self.priono= priono
    self.prio=prio

def create_widgets(self):
    self.add = tk.Button(self, bg ="black", fg="pink")
    self.add["text"] =   "-----Add to queue-----\n(click me)"
    self.add["command"] = self.create_window
    self.add.pack(side="top", pady = 10, padx = 20)
    self.add["font"] = "Times 16 bold"

    self.remov = tk.Button(self, bg ="black", fg="pink")
    self.remov["text"]= "---Remove in queue---\n(click me)"
    self.remov["command"] = self.remov_
    self.remov.pack(side="top", pady = 10, padx = 20)
    self.remov["font"] = "Times 16 bold"

    self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="white", bg = "red",
    command=root.destroy)
    self.quit.pack(side="bottom")

def create_window(self):
    def inputer(self):
        self.L1 = tk.Label(self, text = "Name")
        self.L1.pack( side = LEFT)
        self.E1 = tk.Entry(self, bd =5)
        self.E1.pack(side = RIGHT)
    win2 = Toplevel(self)
    win2.button = Button(self, text='Ready?\nClick Here', command=inputer)

def say_hi(self):
    print("hi there, everyone!")

def add_1(self):
    name=input("What is your name? ")
    first.append(name)
    print("Good Day!",first[self.nom])
    print("Your priority number is:","%03d" % (self.priono))
    self.priono+=1
    self.nom+= 1

def remov_(self):
    if (len(first)) >= 1:
        first.popleft()
    else:
        print("No one left in queue")


root = tk.Tk()
root.config(background="black")

app = Application(master=root)
app.master.title("ID QUEUEING SYSTEM beta")
app.master.minsize(540, 360)
app.master.maxsize(600, 500)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try adding (fill=both, expand=True) when you are packing your frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use your `toplevel` to indicate where the widgets must appear; you must also `pack` (place or grid) the widgets belonging to your toplevel window.

The code from `inputer` needed to be placed outside of the inner function; you can now write the code to have this inputer do what you need it to do:

I removed the star import and added the prefix `tk.` to all `tkinter` method calls.

```
import tkinter as tk
from collections import deque


class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None, nom=0, priono=1, prio=1):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.nom = nom
        self.priono= priono
        self.prio=prio

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.add = tk.Button(self, bg ="black", fg="pink")
        self.add["text"] =   "-----Add to queue-----\n(click me)"
        self.add["command"] = self.create_window
        self.add.pack(side="top", pady = 10, padx = 20)
        self.add["font"] = "Times 16 bold"

        self.remov = tk.Button(self, bg ="black", fg="pink")
        self.remov["text"]= "---Remove in queue---\n(click me)"
        self.remov["command"] = self.remov_
        self.remov.pack(side="top", pady = 10, padx = 20)
        self.remov["font"] = "Times 16 bold"

        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="white", bg = "red",
        command=root.destroy)
        self.quit.pack(side="bottom")

    def create_window(self):
        def inputer():
            print('inputer ', end=': ')
            print(self.E1.get())

        win2 = tk.Toplevel(self)
        win2_button = tk.Button(win2, text='Ready?\nClick Here', command=inputer)
        win2_button.pack()
        self.L1 = tk.Label(win2, text = "Name")
        self.L1.pack( side=tk.LEFT)
        self.E1 = tk.Entry(win2, bd =5)
        self.E1.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

    def say_hi(self):
        print("hi there, everyone!")

    def add_1(self):
        name=input("What is your name? ")
        first.append(name)
        print("Good Day!",first[self.nom])
        print("Your priority number is:","%03d" % (self.priono))
        self.priono+=1
        self.nom+= 1

    def remov_(self):
        if (len(first)) >= 1:
            first.popleft()
        else:
            print("No one left in queue")


root = tk.Tk()
root.config(background="black")

app = Application(master=root)
app.master.title("ID QUEUEING SYSTEM beta")
app.master.minsize(540, 360)
app.master.maxsize(600, 500)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"you must also pack the toplevel"_ - this is not a true statement. Toplevels are standalone windows, you can't pack them into another window.